# Classify points according to euclidean distance - optimize code

Tags: performance, matlab

I have a matrix A consisting of 200 vectors of size d.

I want that a matrix B consisting of 4096 vectors gets classified to these points according to the nearest distance rule.

Thus the result should have rows of size B having the id number ( from 1 to 200 ) to which it belongs.

I have written this code via `2 for` loops and it takes lots of time for calculation.

```
for i = 1:4096
        counter = 1;
        vector1 = FaceImage(i,:);
        vector2 = Centroids(1,:);
        distance = pdist( [ vector1 ; vector2] , 'euclidean' );
        for j = 2:200
              vector2 = Centroids(j,:);
              temp = pdist( [ vector1 ; vector2] , 'euclidean' );
              if temp < distance
                    distance = temp;
                    counter = j;
              end
        end
        Histogram( i ) = counter;
end
```

Can somebody help me out increasing the efficiency of the above code ... or perhaps suggest me an inbuilt function ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this

```
vector2 = Centroids(1,:);
vector = [ vector2 ; FaceImage ];
temp = pdist( vector , 'euclidean' );
answer = temp[1:4096];  % will contain first 4096 lines as distances between vector2 and rows of Face Image
Now you can find the minimum of these distances and that `row + 1` will be the vector that is closest to the point
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in one line with [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/stats/pdist2.html):

```
[~, Histogram] = pdist2( Centroids, FaceImage, 'euclidian', 'Smallest', 1);
```

---

**Timing for original code:**

```
FaceImage = rand(4096, 100);
Centroids = rand(200, 100);

tic
* your code *
toc

Elapsed time is 87.434877 seconds.
```

---

**Timing for my code:**

```
tic
[~, Histogram_2] = pdist2( Centroids, FaceImage, 'euclidean', 'Smallest', 1);
toc

Elapsed time is 0.111736 seconds.
```

---

**Asserting the results are the same:**

```
>> all(Histogram==Histogram_2)

ans =

   1
```